# Why did Dusty not use the internet?

Tags: plot-explanation, planes-fire-and-rescue

In the movie *Planes: Fire and Rescue* the plot is quite simple: Dusty is broken and no one knows where spare part could be. It bothers me every time I see this fairy tale why Dusty and his friends did not use internet for search.

What we know

- Internet exists in this world and Dusty's friends used it in the movie *Planes* to promote Dusty
- Dusty is a well known celebrity
- At least someone around Dusty should be able to use the internet

If they used the internet, the chances would be much better in finding spare parts.

So, why didn't they?

Comment: I dunno, maybe it's just a different internet than ours because it's a different world run by vehicles. Aren't those basically body parts to them? Are there many sites in *our* internet that sell organs?

Comment: On the deep Web anything is possible

Answer (score 4):

Because they are Plot-Dumb, a trope where a character it characters do not do an incredibly easy or logical thing, as a means for the writer to advance the plot. It is called 
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IdiotPlot
by tv tropes, coined by famous movie critic Ebert.

Had they used the Internet, the movie would either be 4 minutes long, or they would have to shoe horn a scene where the characters say "my Google fu is weak" or "everyone online is out of stock or charging too much". The scene would add nothing to the plot. So the writer skips over it to speed things up.